# Laravel 5.2 with rails.js - DELETE throws TokenMismatchException

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, laravel, laravel-5

I'm struggling with the implementation of rails.js to do `DELETE-requests` without using forms.

```
<a href="{{route('admin.user.destroy', $user)}}" data-method="delete" data-token="{csrf_token()}" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Delete User</a>
```

But everytime after confirming, it tells me, that my token seems to be wrong.
Tried to use the `web-middleware` instead of the `auth` but no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, by adding this to the header:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="<?= csrf_token() ?>" />
<meta name="csrf-param" content="_token" />
```